# How to capture all packets in mininet without duplications?

Tags: mininet

I created a mininet network (single) with 4 hosts and one switch. and try to capture packets using Wireshark (open Wireshark from the terminal of Ubuntu (not a single host). The problem which interface I have to select?
the available interfaces:
eth0
s1-eth1
s1-eth2
s1-eth3
s1-eth4
any
loopback: lo

the problem:

- If I select s1-eth1 it will just show packets from and to host 1. and the same issue if I select similar interfaces s1-eth2, s1-eth3....
- when use loopback (lo): it just show the local IP (127.0.0.1) and the OFPT_PACET_IN for first time when the sender connect to a new host, the next transactions are not shown.
- when use (any): it shows the results two times (I think one from the sender interface and the next from the receiver side interface) in addition to 127.0.0.1

I need to see all packets in the network from any host to any destination without duplications